# How to trigger "wp_handle_upload_prefilter" filter when uploading an image programatically?

Tags: images, filters, testing, uploads

I am sanitizing uploaded SVG files with `wp_handle_upload_prefilter`, example:

```
// Example code
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', function($file) {
    if ( $file['type'] === 'image/svg+xml' ) {
        $this->sanitize( $file['tmp_name'] );
    }
} );
```

It works fine for files uploaded through the Media Library, however, if the file is uploaded programatically, it doesn't go through the filter.

The reason I want to programatically upload an image is for testing purposes. I am uploading the file with `wp_upload_bits` function:

```
$upload = wp_upload_bits( 'xss.svg', null, file_get_contents( $this->svg_path ) );
$uploaded_svg_contents = file_get_contents( $upload['file'] );

$this->assertFalse( $upload['error'] );
$this->assertNotContains( '<script', $uploaded_svg_contents );
```

How can I upload a media file programatically, that goes through the `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` filter?

Comment: there's a plugin to auto-sanitize SVGs, additionally, SVGs aren't always `image/svg+xml`, they can be `text/xml` or `image/svg` and a few others. Also, why use `wp_upload_bits`? There are much higher level functions for sideloading files into attachments taht take all the work out of it

Comment: Hi @TomJNowell, this approach was taken from "Safe SVG" plugin, same author from this package https://packagist.org/packages/enshrined/svg-sanitize. I'm trying to get only the sanitization process without adding third-party plugins

Comment: `image/svg+xml` is the mime specified in the `upload_mimes` filter: `add_filter( 'upload_mimes', function($mimes) { $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml'; return $mimes }`

Comment: hmmm why? If you're copying the code it's still going to be just as fast/slow wether it's in a plugin or your themes `functions.php`. I've reviewed that plugins code myself, it's already quite lean and fast

Comment: @TomJNowell there was already a class to add support to SVG, and it does some things specific to our projects. Since I just needed to add sanitization to it, I thought a third-party plugin would be a little overhead. But yes, using a plugin is a great solution, too, I will study this SVG Support class and see if I can deprecate it in favor of a plugin maintained by a third-party

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got this. Solution was to use `wp_handle_upload()` function. Kinda obvious, when I come to think about it...

```
function handle_upload( string $path ): array {
    $filename        = basename( $path );
    $random_filename = rand( 0, 1000 ) . $filename;
    $tmp_path        = str_replace( $filename, $random_filename, $path );

    /** Create a temporary copy of the original file, since it will be moved during the upload process */
    copy( $path, $tmp_path );

    if ( file_exists( $tmp_path ) ) {
        $_files_mimic = [
            'name'     => $random_filename,
            'type'     => 'image/svg+xml',
            'tmp_name' => $tmp_path,
            'error'    => 0,
            'size'     => filesize( $tmp_path ),
        ];

        return wp_handle_upload( $_files_mimic, [
            'action'    => 'test_svg_upload',
            'test_form' => false,
        ] );
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException( 'Could not copy test file from ' . $path . ' to ' . $tmp_path );
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$upload_response = handle_upload('path/to/my/image.jpg');
```

Now if you debug `$upload_response['file']`, you should have your media processed by `wp_handle_upload_filter`, so you can test it or something.